# Spring save record and send message rollbacks

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have a class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
class MyService{
   @Autowired MyTableRepository repository;
   @Autowired FacebookMessageSender sender;

   public void updateTableAndSendMessage(MyTable m){
      m.setProcessed(1);
      repository.save(m);
      sender.sendMessageToFacebook(m);
   }
}
```

Somewhere in the code:

```
List<MyTable> list=repository.findByProcessed(0);
for(MyTable m:list){
   myService.process(m);
}
```

So, I have the following:
In the quartz job I retrieve all records with processed flag set to 0. Then I pass it to service, then processed flag becomes 1 and system sends message to Facebook messenger (wherever). But, if there's a sql exception occurs, before or after 'process' method execution, transaction will be rolled back and flag will be still 0. So Facebook message will be sent on next job launch, and again and again. I tried to break it down to 2 methods, one saves flag other sends message. But then what if message was not sent and I will have to rollback the transaction? So it's like deadlock. I need prevent FB message from being send on other exception and rollback DB changes on FB sending failure. How to do that in spring-data, afaik transaction will be committed after method ends. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code structure should work:

> **Service** class

```
@Service
class TaskService {
  @Autowired TaskRepository        repository;
  @Autowired FacebookMessageSender sender;

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void sendTaskNotification(Task task){
    try {
      task.setProcessed(1);
      repository.save(task);

      sender.sendMessageToFacebook(task);
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
      throw new RuntimeException(t);
    }
  }
}
```

> Caller class

```
@Component
class TaskNotificationJob {
  @Autowired TaskService service;

  @Scheduled
  @Transactional
  public void sendTaskNotifications() {
    for(Task task : repository.findByProcessed(0)) {
      try {
        service.sendTaskNotification(task);
      }
      catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // Log the error, but don't rethrow the exception.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Explanation

#### a. Ensure that a Facebook message is not attempted if task cannot be saved

If a single task cannot be saved, an exception will be raised and the code will skip the part that attempts to send a Facebook message for the task. Therefore, this requirement is automatically met due to the way the code is structured.

#### b. Ensure that an error while sending a Facebook message rolls back the task

The lines `catch(Throwable t) { throw new RuntimeException(t); }` ensure that if any exception (including one that derives from `Exception` instead of `RuntimeException`) is thrown while either saving a task or sending a Facebook message for it, it gets re-thrown as a `RuntimeException`. This in turn will ensure that the `@Transactional` annotation surrounding the method will roll the database transaction back.

#### c. Ensure that an error while processing a task does not affect other tasks

Each task is processed in its own transaction (`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`) so anything that gets committed before an error occurs, stays committed.

When an error occurs, the calling code catches it (`catch (RuntimeException e)`) so that the error does not bubble up to the transaction handler for the caller and caller is allowed to attempt and process remaining tasks, as required. Not having this catch clause would mean that the first `RuntimeException` raised in the service will also bubble up to the caller and will terminate the whole operation immediately, potentially leaving unprocessed tasks. It is important not to re-throw the caught exception at this point because re-throwing it would bubble it up and hence defeat the purpose of having the catch clause in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, but this will not work, because in TaskService  method   repository.save(task); will be committed after sendTaskNotification method exited, but by that time facebook message will be already sent. That's why it's so tricky. Thanks

Comment: @avalon , isn't that what you want - either both steps are executed or none is executed?